# Unfortunately, “App Name” has stopped in Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-emulator

So I am new to Android Programming and am trying to make my own true false quiz App. 
However when I try to run the app to see if I am doing this right the emulator shows "Unfortunately, QuizMe has stopped.", where QuizMe is name of the App.

The QuizMeActivity file:

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class QuizMeActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    //Variables
    //Buttons
    private Button mTrueButton;
    private Button mFalseButton;
    //Image Buttons
    private ImageButton mNext;
    //Text View
    private TextView mQuestionText;
    private TextView mAnswerBox;
    //Integer, to keep track of location in array
    private int mCurrentIndex = 0;
    //boolean to hold the answer type
    boolean isTrue;

    //create an array of TrueFalse to hold each question with answer
    private TrueFalse[] mQuestionBankFailed = new TrueFalse[] {
            new TrueFalse(R.string.questionOne, R.string.answerOne),
            new TrueFalse(R.string.questionTwo, R.string.answerTwo),
            new TrueFalse(R.string.questionThree, R.string.answerThree),
            new TrueFalse(R.string.questionFour, R.string.answerFour),
            new TrueFalse(R.string.questionFive, R.string.answerFive)
    };

    //create an array of TrueFalse to hold each question with the answer boolean
    private TrueFalse[] mQuestionBank = new TrueFalse[] {
            new TrueFalse(R.string.questionOne, false),
            new TrueFalse(R.string.questionTwo, false),
            new TrueFalse(R.string.questionThree, true),
            new TrueFalse(R.string.questionFour, true),
            new TrueFalse(R.string.questionFive, true)
    };

    //add methods

    //to update the question in screen
    private void updateQues(){
        int question = mQuestionBank[mCurrentIndex].isQuestion();
        mQuestionText.setText(question);

    }

    //check the answer:
    //when user presses true
    private void checkAnswerTrue(){
        //answer to the question
        isTrue = mQuestionBank[mCurrentIndex].isAnswerType();


        if(isTrue == true){
            mAnswerBox.setText(R.string.C);
        }
        else{
            mAnswerBox.setText(R.string.W);
        }

    }

    //when the user presses false
    private void checkAnswerFalse(){
        //answer to the question
        isTrue = mQuestionBank[mCurrentIndex].isAnswerType();


        if(isTrue == false){
            mAnswerBox.setText(R.string.C);
        }
        else{
            mAnswerBox.setText(R.string.W);
        }

    }


    //generated methods

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_quiz_me);

        mQuestionText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.question_label);

        mTrueButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonT);
        mTrueButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                checkAnswerTrue();

            }
        });
        mFalseButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                checkAnswerFalse();

            }
        });



    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.quiz_me, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

The TrueFalse class

```
public class TrueFalse {

    //variables
    private int mQuestion, mAnswerQuestion;
    private boolean mAnswerType;

    /*
     * Constructor
     * sets the variables equal 
     * to the parameter
     * 
     */
    public TrueFalse(int question, int answer) {

        mQuestion = question;
        mAnswerQuestion = answer;

    }

    //overload constructor
    public TrueFalse(int question, boolean answer){

        mQuestion = question;
        mAnswerType = answer;

    }


    /*
     * @return the answerType
     */
    public boolean isAnswerType() {
        return mAnswerType;
    }

    /*
     * @param answerType the answerType to set
     */
    public void setAnswerType(boolean answerType) {
        mAnswerType = answerType;
    }

    /*
     * @return the Question
     */
    public int isQuestion() {
        return mQuestion;
    }

    /*
     * @param Question the mQuestion to set
     */
    public void setQuestion(int question) {
        this.mQuestion = question;
    }

    /*
     * @return the AnswerQuestion
     */
    public int isAnswerQuestion() {
        return mAnswerQuestion;
    }

    /*
     * @param AnswerQuestion the mAnswerQuestion to set
     */
    public void setAnswerQuestion(int answer) {
        this.mAnswerQuestion = answer;
    }



}
```

This is my activity_quiz_me file

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="mugrai.luvneesh.quizme.QuizMeActivity" >

    <!-- android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" -->
    <!-- android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin" -->
    <!-- android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin" -->
    <!-- android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" -->

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/question_label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="@string/questionOne"
        android:textSize="25sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonT"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/question_label"
        android:layout_marginEnd="44dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="44dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:text="@string/True" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonF"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/buttonT"
        android:layout_marginEnd="44dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="44dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="@string/False" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/answerBox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/buttonF"
        android:layout_marginEnd="130dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="130dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="44dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="TEMP" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The string xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <!-- Questions and Answers -->
    <string name="app_name">QuizMe</string>
    <string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
    <string name="questionOne">The average person will shed 10 pounds of skin during their lifetime.</string>
    <string name="answerOne">False</string>
    <string name="questionTwo">You can lead a cow down starts but not upstairs.</string>
    <string name="answerTwo">False</string>
    <string name="questionThree">Google was originally called "Backrub."</string>
    <string name="answerThree">True</string>
    <string name="questionFour">President Calvin coolidge had a pet Racoon.</string>
    <string name="answerFour">True</string>
    <string name="questionFive">Approximately one quarter of human bones are in the feet.</string>
    <string name="answerFive">True</string>

    <!-- Buttons -->
    <string name="True">True</string>
    <string name="False">False</string>

    <!-- Right/Wrong -->
    <string name="C">Correct</string>
    <string name="W">Wrong</string>


</resources>
```

This is the AndroidManifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="mugrai.luvneesh.quizme"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat" >
        <activity
            android:name=".QuizMeActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

This is the LogCat

```
10-13 05:45:36.124: E/AndroidRuntime(788): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-13 05:45:36.124: E/AndroidRuntime(788): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{mugrai.luvneesh.quizme/mugrai.luvneesh.quizme.QuizMeActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-13 05:45:36.124: E/AndroidRuntime(788):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
10-13 05:45:36.124: E/AndroidRuntime(788):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
10-13 05:45:36.124: E/AndroidRuntime(788):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
10-13 05:45:36.124: E/AndroidRuntime(788):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
10-13 05:45:36.124: E/AndroidRuntime(788):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-13 05:45:36.124: E/AndroidRuntime(788):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-13 05:45:36.124: E/AndroidRuntime(788):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
10-13 05:45:36.124: E/AndroidRuntime(788):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-13 05:45:36.124: E/AndroidRuntime(788):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-13 05:45:36.124: E/AndroidRuntime(788):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
10-13 05:45:36.124: E/AndroidRuntime(788):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
10-13 05:45:36.124: E/AndroidRuntime(788):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-13 05:45:36.124: E/AndroidRuntime(788): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-13 05:45:36.124: E/AndroidRuntime(788):  at mugrai.luvneesh.quizme.QuizMeActivity.onCreate(QuizMeActivity.java:106)
10-13 05:45:36.124: E/AndroidRuntime(788):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
10-13 05:45:36.124: E/AndroidRuntime(788):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
10-13 05:45:36.124: E/AndroidRuntime(788):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
10-13 05:45:36.124: E/AndroidRuntime(788):  ... 11 more
```

Also this is what the emulator looks like when it shows the message
http://gyazo.com/2573198c16c0e357ea960958059214e3

Thank you for any advice and help in advance.

Comment: What is the line 106 in QuizMe Activity?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 3):

I think you forget to initialize your `buttonF`

```
mFalseButton= (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonF);
```

and without it you directly set OnClickListner `mFalseButton.setOnClickListener(....)` so you got NPE.